# Android- Tabs with Icons, Class Not Found

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

I been trying to run this project extracted or from this [ViewPagerIndicator Library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsWithIcons.java). 
I am not sure what I missed in copying the codes from the project above. Thanks in advance.^^

**SampleTabsWithIcons**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;
    import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;

    public class SampleTabsWithIcons extends FragmentActivity {
        private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Calendar", "Camera", "Alarms", "Location" };
        private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
                R.drawable.perm_group_calendar,
                R.drawable.perm_group_camera,
                R.drawable.perm_group_device_alarms,
                R.drawable.perm_group_location,
        };


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_tabs_with_icons);

            FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            indicator.setViewPager(pager);
        }

        class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
            public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
            }

            @Override public int getIconResId(int index) {
              return ICONS[index];
            }

          @Override
            public int getCount() {
              return CONTENT.length;
            }
        }
    }
```

**activity_sample_tabs_with_icons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**LOGCAT:**

```
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabwithicon/com.example.tabwithicon.SampleTabsWithIcons}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tabwithicon.SampleTabsWithIcons
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tabwithicon.SampleTabsWithIcons
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
07-12 09:56:22.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15435):    ... 11 more
```

**Here is the structure:**
[image]

**LogCat:**

```
07-12 10:32:27.415: W/dalvikvm(15756): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/tabwithicon/SampleTabsWithIcons; (18)
07-12 10:32:27.418: W/dalvikvm(15756): Link of class 'Lcom/example/tabwithicon/SampleTabsWithIcons;' failed
07-12 10:32:27.419: D/AndroidRuntime(15756): Shutting down VM
07-12 10:32:27.422: W/dalvikvm(15756): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41989300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your logcat is `ClassNotFoundException`. See the line...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tabwithicon.SampleTabsWithIcons
```

You have the class so it should probably be the `package declaration`. Check if you have defined the correct package in your application.

Your package is defined as `com.example.tabwithicon`. Check if that is correct package.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try to add another screen shot.